# Matrix RREF Generalized Solution Infinite Solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got a matrix with $3$ variables, $2$ of which has an infinite number of solutions:

\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2&|&1\\0&0&0&|&0\\0&0&0&|&0\end{bmatrix}

I've turned this into the following set:

$x_1 = 1 + x_2 + 2x_3$
$x_2 = s$
$x_3 = t$

I'm supposed to generalize this into the following form:
$(1,0,0) + s(1,1,0) + t(2,0,1) \qquad \forall s,t \in \mathbb{R} $

However, I have no idea what steps are taken to do this. I've tried substitution without success. I can only understand how the constant portion $(1,0,0)$ works, which is pretty elementary looking at the matrix. The  $s(1,1,0)$ & $t(2,0,1)$ parts are totally unclear to me. Can someone help me bridge the gap with how to get from the set to the final generalized solution? As much detail as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see it this way?

$\begin{cases} x_1=1+x_2+2x_3 \\ x_2=s \\ x_3=t \end{cases}$

Now you can put the $x_2=s$ and $x_3=t$ to the first equation to get the $x_1=1+s+2t$. So the 3 equation becames:

$\begin{cases} x_1=1+s+2t \\ x_2=s \\ x_3=t \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} x_1=1+1s+2t \\ x_2=0+1s+0t \\ x_3=0+0s+1t \end{cases}$

And now you can treat it as a vector:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+1s+2t\\0+1s+0t\\0+0s+1t\end{bmatrix}=1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

You can see it by adding the 3 vector together:
$$1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1s\\1s\\0s\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}2t\\0t\\1t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+1s+2t\\0+1s+0t\\0+0s+1t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes that helps a ton. Can you give me one more piece of intuition on the s[ ] and t[ ] parts here... Are you deliberately setting s = 1 and t = 0 then looking at the equation to determine what to put for s[ ], then doing s = 0 and t = 1 for t[ ]?

Comment: @TimLindsey In the vector, you have the cofactors of the $1$,$t$,$s$. I've edited my answer, it might be better now. Tell me if there is still something unclear.